# How to use java like objects in php( CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

I want to use objects(java style) in my PHP code after by instantiating objects after getting their properties from database and use them as objects from that point on. Does this work in PHP? If yes,where should I place my classes in the codeigniter directories?

```
$object=object_constructor($this->model_name->function_that_fetches_object_properties());
```

Comment: you could use PDO to fetch a row into an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is what is called an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) which codeigniter does not have "out of the box".

There are some that integrate it [with Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/cookbook/code-igniter-and-doctrine/en), I would recommend you look at other php frameworks that have a built in ORM, one that is somewhat similar to codeigniter in approach is [FuelPHP](http://fuelphp.com).  It is approaching a stable release and has been enjoyable for me to work with.

ORM example in FuelPHP:

```
$entry = Model_Article::find(4);
$entry->title = 'My first edit';
$entry->author = 'Total n00b';
$entry->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use PEAR's [DB_DataObject](http://pear.php.net/package/DB_DataObject) which does exactly this kind of mapping, including fetching related objects.